# C++ allocating node pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, nodes

I'm making a C++ Maze program using disjoint sets and the Union/Find operations.

I have a `MakeSet(int x)` function which creates a new Node for every integer element x in the maze.  (i.e `1 to 16` for a 4x4 maze). Thus initially every element is in its own set.

My MakeSet looks like this

```
void Maze::MakeSet(int x)
{
    Node *root = new Node;
    root->label = x;
    root->parent = NULL;
}
```

But in the CreateMaze() function I have to call MakeSet many times to get all the elements into their own set initially. Thus, the root will keep being overwritten. How do I dynamically allocate many different nodes? Should I keep them separated in an array?

Comment: Does your code really look like that? It allocates a new node, and then looses all references to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already *allocate* a new `Node`, you are just not *keeping* it. You need to change the function to return `Node*`, and store the results in an array or a vector.

```
Node* Maze::MakeSet(int x) {
    Node *root = new Node;
    root->label = x;
    root->parent = NULL;
    return root;
}

Node *nodes[16];
for (int i = 0 ; i != 16 ; i++) {
    nodes[i] = Maze::MakeSet(i);
}
```

An even better approach would be to do `Node` initialization in a *constructor*:

```
Node::Node(int x) : label(x), parent(NULL) {
}
```

You can now create all sets in a loop, and store pointers to them in an array:

```
Node *nodes[16];
for (int i = 0 ; i != 16 ; i++) {
    nodes[i] = new Node(i);
}
```

Comment: So when I do a Union(int label1, int label2), I have to go into their respective array locations, right? Then how would I connect the two nodes?

Comment: @CyberShot Add member functions to `Node` to implement the two common operations - an instance member `getRoot`, and a static member `union` to implement set union. The `getRoot` would traverse the chain up to the root, and set all nodes' parents to the eventual root found in the search. By the way, it's more common to set `parent` to `this` than to `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, but another quick question. Once I get the node from the array via, Node *s = getNode(item1); Any subsequent union() won't change s in the array right? since it only returns a copy. How do I make it actually change the pointers in the nodes[] array? i.e how do I make getNode() return a reference to the nodes in the nodes[] array instead of pass by value? i.e BTNode **s = &getNode(item1); and then *s->parent = x; actually changes s in the global nodes[] array

Comment: @CyberShot Assuming a typical implementation of disjoint sets, you do not need to change pointers in the nodes array. Set equality is determined by the equality of their "root" `parent` pointers (i.e. parent pointers traversed all the way up, until there's nowhere to go). Initially, each root pointer is set to the node itself, so all sets are different. In the course of performing a union of `a` and `b` you either set `a->parent=b` or `b->parent=a`. So you never modify `nodes[i]`, only `nodes[i]->parent`.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `std::vector` of `Node` objects or pointers as a class member:

```
class Maze
{
   std::vector<Node> nodes;
};
```

or, if you must

```
class Maze
{
   std::vector<Node*> nodes;
}
```

and add the created nodes:

```
void Maze::MakeSet(int x)
{
    Node *root = new Node;
    root->label = x;
    root->parent = NULL;
    nodes.push_back(root);
}
```

Note that you'll have to implement a destructor to clean up the memory when you're done. This also means you should have a copy constructor and assignment operator for `Maze`.